# Close pixelate js issue

Tags: javascript, plugins

I am using David Desandro's js plugin Close Pixelate in order to pixelate thumbnail images on a site.

```
   function init() {
        document.getElementById('work-thumb-1').closePixelate([
            { resolution: 10 }
    ]);
    };
    window.addEventListener( 'load', init, false);
```

I need to target multiple selectors with the same name so the getElementById method is no good?

Comment: I don't know that library, but looking at the plugin's syntax, it may not be possible, as it seems to be extending the DOM object itself and may not be designed to be applied on collections of DOM objects. But do you really have a pressing reason to do so?

Comment: do you use any library like jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a library than this should be more simple, but you can also do it by only javascript,

## Pure Javascript

```
function init() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByName('nameofelements');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].closePixelate([
            {resolution: 10}
        ]);
    }
};
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

## jQuery

```
function init() {
    $('[name="nameofelements"]').each(function() {
        $(this).closePixelate([
            {resolution: 10}
        ]);
    });

};
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```